# Code that adjust picturebox according to screen resolution

Tags: vb.net

Ok so i have created a program,well not exactly a program but some kind of a full screen form that has animations(with pictureboxes)...

and the problem is,well i made that "program" on 1366x768 screen resolution, and when i tried to run that "program" on my other desktop (1024x768) it was,well not good, so i was just wondering is it possible to write a code that adjust picbox position according to screen resolution...

i tried something with this code

Dim ScrWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

Dim ScrHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

and then i used scrwidth and scrheight but i did nothing..

Comment: Where and how did you use the variables?

Comment: not important. :D it didn't work

Comment: *Well*, most of the time people are looking for help here, their code isn't working - but should still be posted to give people something to work with.

Comment: well i haven't used that variables for positioning i used them for animations

Comment: like   If Me.PictureBox1.Left >= ScrWidth Then
            x = -5
            flipPicx = True

Comment: @user3425891, That was the most important part was how you used them. If done incorrectly your results would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention it, I'm not sure what you did with scrwidth and scrheight, but this is how you resize a picturebox:

```
pictureBox1.Size = New Size(Width, Height)
```

of course you need to consider the aspect ratio yourself. It's not going to do it for you.

as in (pseudo code):

```
ratio = current_width/current_height
new_width = whatever
new_height = whatever/ratio
```